# UIButton Event for Delete Row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I add button in UITableView cell. My code is

```
UIButton *btnView = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd] retain];
    btnView.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 8.0, 25.0, 25.0);

    //[btnView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"invite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnView addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnView];
    [btnView release];
```

My button action is

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
{

}
```

I want to know, how to get current table row index when click. I want to delete table row when click on button.

Edit::
I found a way for delete with animation

```
[listOfItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Comment: your code says "UIButtonTypeContactAdd", not delete, so it is kinda confusing.

Comment: when add , it will remove from current uitableview and add into another UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one approach is to store the row number in the button tag

```
btnView.tag = [indexPath row]
```

in the action

```
- (void)action:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton)sender;
    int row = btn.tag;
}
```

Comment: I'm using int row=[sender tag];

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    UIView *contentView = [button superview];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[contentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //Do something
}
```

Depending on the layout of your UITableViewCell it is possible that you have to traverse deeper into your TableViewCell Views.

Answer (score 0):

http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/ Use an associated object of a NSNumber surrounding the row or the index path itself as the associated object

```
//when you create the button
objc_setAssociatedObject(button, associationKeyForButton, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);


//in the touch up inside handler to get the row back.
NSNumber* rowNumber = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, associationKeyForButton);
```